# Remove class and then add back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a header navigation listed below, and the class added to the `li` creates an icon.

**When scrolling down I want to be able to remove the class completely and when scrolling back to the top of the page I want to be able to tell which class belongs to which item and add that same class back**.

I am thinking I probably need to store them into variables.  Keep in mind these menu items are dynamic and can change if it's deleted.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu-left-main-nav" class="main-left-nav nav-bar hide-for-small">
    <li id="menu-item-37" class="customicon-shop"><a href="http://localhost:8888/shop/">Shop</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-35" class="customicon-contact"><a href="http://localhost:8888/account/">Account</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-36" class="customicon-apps"><a href="http://localhost:8888/apps-entertainment/">Apps &amp; Entertainment</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="menu-right-main-nav" class="main-right-nav nav-bar hide-for-small">
    <li id="menu-item-61" class="customicon-about"><a href="http://localhost:8888/about/">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-62" class="customicon-support"><a href="http://localhost:8888/support/">Support</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-63" class="customicon-why"><a href="http://localhost:8888/why/">Why?</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var nav = $(".nav");
var pos = nav.position();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        nav.css({
            'position': 'fixed'
        }).addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        nav.css({
            'position': 'relative'
        }).removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

If you look at the code, the id's will be dynamic but the classes will not be.

Comment: why not just add a hover state to the li item and hide or show the icon based on that?

Comment: by the way, have you looked into scrollspy? If I understand your question correctly, you want to highlight the part of the menu the user is currently scrolling past, right?

Comment: `class="nav"` is not defined anywhere

Comment: I am curious if it scrolls out of view why you would need to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store arbitrary data in any element with jQuery's data function

HTML

```
    <ul id="menu-left-main-nav" class="main-left-nav nav-bar hide-for-small">
        <li id="menu-item-37" class="customicon-shop" data-icon="customicon-shop"><a href="http://localhost:8888/shop/">Shop</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-35" class="customicon-contact" data-icon="customicon-contact"><a href="http://localhost:8888/account/">Account</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-36" class="customicon-apps" data-icon="customicon-apps"><a href="http://localhost:8888/apps-entertainment/">Apps &amp; Entertainment</a></li>
    </ul>
```

JS, when you're scrolling back to top

```
  jQuery('#menu-left-main-nav li, #menu-right-main-nav li').each(function() {
      var originalclass = jQuery(this).data('icon');
      jQuery(this).addClass(originalclass);
  });
```

Comment: `, menu-left-main-nav ` selects nothing

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't combine jquery `.css` and `.addClass` when you can do this all within the class rule.
2. You only need 1 class, and that is `.sticky` to apply the position: fixed; and top: 0; to the `<ul>` element.

Use `.toggleClass` to add `.sticky`, no need to add any css or classes for `position: relative;` or when they scroll up the page, just remove the class `.sticky`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var pos = $(".nav").position();
  $(".nav").toggleClass('sticky', $(window).scrollTop() > pos.top);
});
```

and use CSS for the class of .sticky:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

So, with this approach, it will just add the `sticky` class when the page gets scrolled down, when they scroll up it will remove the class automatically.

It is not clear what `$(".nav")` represents in your jQuery code above.  If you are referring to the HTML 5 `<nav>` element, than the code above should work, if you remove the `.` from everywhere it says `$(".nav")`, so it would become `$("nav")`

Comment: You are probably on the right track PLEASE DON'T SHOUT not please.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I too thought initially the same. But then apparently he was trying to use bullets. Instead of 1. he used #1.  EDITED.

Comment: Opps, didn't realize that was a shout...  my bad.  Just used a hashtag for the number, didn't know it would cause it to shout.  Sorry...

Comment: @SolomonClosson Don't worry. Edited.

Comment: Now if we can just figure out what `.nav` actually IS in the OP's code.

Comment: OMG, I think the OP is actually referring the HTML 5 `<nav>` element, which would be the parent of the `ul`, but not sure.  If that is the case, than would just need to remove the `.` from `$(".nav")`

Comment: Thanks Solomon for the clarification however without spending a lot of time on it, by doing that it causes it to flicker each time you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom data attribute to the li tags that will contain the appropriate class name and then add and remove it as follows.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu-left-main-nav" class="main-left-nav nav-bar hide-for-small">
    <li id="menu-item-37" data-icon-class="customicon-shop"><a href="http://localhost:8888/shop/">Shop</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-35" data-icon-class="customicon-contact"><a href="http://localhost:8888/account/">Account</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-36" data-icon-class="customicon-apps"><a href="http://localhost:8888/apps-entertainment/">Apps &amp; Entertainment</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="menu-right-main-nav" class="main-right-nav nav-bar hide-for-small">
    <li id="menu-item-61" data-icon-class="customicon-about"><a href="http://localhost:8888/about/">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-62" data-icon-class="customicon-support"><a href="http://localhost:8888/support/">Support</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-63" data-icon-class="customicon-why"><a href="http://localhost:8888/why/">Why?</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var $listItems = $('.nav-bar li'),
    itemIconClass = $listItem.attr('data-icon-class');

// add class
$listItem.addClass(itemIconClass);

// remove class
$listItem.removeClass(itemIconClass);
```

Comment: `$('#menu-item-61')` dynamic id, will vary per notes

Comment: Yeah, I figured this would get you started. You could also use the '.nav-bar li' as a selector as well.

Comment: To answer everyones questions, the scrolling works fine and the header becomes sticky so that isn't the issue.  The issue is when I scroll the page down and the header becomes sticky, I want to remove classes for the `<li>` items and in this sense it would remove the web fonts.  The code for nav is this `<div class="nav">
<div class="nav-container"><nav><?php bones_main_left_nav(); ?><?php bones_main_right_nav(); ?></nav></div></div>`

Comment: With that being said, I am curious about how to store the classes that are in each list item and when scrolling down I remove all classes with jQuery, which I have, but when scrolling back up I need to add those exact classes back once the top of the page is reached.

Comment: Anyone with any input?

Comment: I've modified the code above to show you how to select list items using the class name rather than the id. This should adequately demonstrate how to add and remove the class names since the class name is being stored as a data-attribute on the element. Does this help or no?

Comment: Thanks bbone and amenadiel. Between both of the comments I got it working.  Thanks again!